# Using T-Sql, how can I insert from one table on a remote server into another table on my local server?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Given the remote server 'Production' (currently accessible via an IP) and the local database 'Development', how can I run an `INSERT` into 'Development' from 'Production' using T-SQL?

I'm using MS SQL 2005 and the table structures are a lot different between the two databases hence the need for me to manually write some migration scripts.

**UPDATE:**

T-SQL really isn't my bag. I've tried the following (not knowing what I'm doing):

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver 
    @server = N'20.0.0.1\SQLEXPRESS', 
    @srvproduct=N'SQL Server' ;

GO

EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin '20.0.0.1\SQLEXPRESS', 'false', 
    'Domain\Administrator', 'sa', 'saPassword'

SELECT * FROM [20.0.0.1\SQLEXPRESS].[DatabaseName].[dbo].[Table]
```

And I get the error:

> Login failed for user ''. The user is
>   not associated with a trusted SQL
>   Server connection.

Comment: see the addition in my answer..the '20.0.0.1\SQLEXPRESS' server is the production box right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

create a [linked server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff772782.aspx) and then use 4 part notation

```
insert table
select <column names>
from LinkedserverName.DatabaseName.SchemaName.TableName
```

you can also use [OPENROWSET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx)

example

```
insert table
SELECT a.*
FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'Server=Seattle1;Trusted_Connection=yes;',
     'SELECT GroupName, Name, DepartmentID
      FROM AdventureWorks2008R2.HumanResources.Department
      ORDER BY GroupName, Name') AS a;
```

try this to create the login

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname=N'20.0.0.1\SQLEXPRESS',
@useself=N'False',
@locallogin=NULL,
@rmtuser=N'sa',
@rmtpassword='saPassword'
```

Comment: +1 for ease of use and example.  However, make sure you don't forget the brackets if/where necessary.  ie, [LinkedserverName].[DatabaseName].[SchemaName].[TableName]  My scripts will not run without at least the first 2 sets of brackets.

Comment: I'm trying to use linked servers, but I'm getting the error `Login failed for user ''. The user is not associated with a trusted SQL Server connection.`. Any ideas?

Comment: @GenericTypeTae Has the server to be linked in mixed mode authentication or only integrated authentication?

Comment: @bernd_k - It's setup with Mixed.

Comment: @genericTypetea You can configure the assignment of local credentials to remote server  credentials http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188477%28SQL.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can define the PROD Server as Linked Server to the DEV box and then access it.
However I think it would be easier to get a backup from PROD Box and Restore it to DEV or use SSIS for Schema Import.

Answer (score 1):

Look into the [RedGate](http://www.red-gate.com) tools, esp. SQL Data Compare.  If that's not an option you should look at [OPENDATASOURCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179856.aspx) or [OPENROWSET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx) to access the remote database.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use a linked server and then use the 4 part names for objects (See BOL for how to set up a linked server)
Or you could use SSIS to set up the data migrations and connect to the remote server
Or you could use OPENROWSET

I'd probably use SSIS, but I'm already familiar with it.

Answer (score 0):

Use SSMS.  Right click on the target DB and select "Tasks", "Import Data".  You will be able to preview the data and make conversions visually.  Save the package in SSIS or run it now.