# insert into remote server table without ssis and dts

Tags: sql-server-2008

My requirement is to create a stored procedure that joins two tables and inserts it into a remote server table.

How can I solve this without using ssis and any import/export data?

Answer (score 0):

please

1. use the search before asking your question
2. Be more specific, stackoverflow is not here to write your whole program, people assist you
3. Use punctations marks and have a look at your format

**Your question**

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4521670/using-t-sql-how-can-i-insert-from-one-table-on-a-remote-server-into-another-tab), it shows you how to do that. You can first add a linked server(thats the destionation in your case) and then use it for your insert statement.